# jquery single variable declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, browserify

I have a problem related to variable declaration. I use browserify, so here I have to require jquery before bootstrap.js. The issue is that I can't undestand what is the problem with the first variant of code?

```
var $, jQuery;
$ = jQuery = require('./libs/jquery/jquery.min');
require('./libs/bootstrap/bootstrap');
```

and

```
var $ = jQuery = require('./libs/jquery/jquery.min');
require('./libs/bootstrap/bootstrap');
```

First variant doesn't work (console shows me an error that bootstrap needs jquery), second variant is not good enough for Jshint but it works great! Can someone explain why the first variant doesn't work

Comment: i do my like `global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');` jquery installed via NPM

Comment: @SimonDavies thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your answer:

Your first variant creates no global variables:

```
var $,jQuery
```

created two variables - `$`, and `jQuery` in the local scope.

The second one:

```
var $ = jQuery = ...
```

created one global variable `jQuery` and one local variable `$`. The first variant doesn't work because bootstrap is looking for the global variable `jQuery` and it can't find it.